# Creating Azure WebJobs?

Tags: azure

Does anyone know what this article is talking about?
[Run Background tasks with WebJobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/)

The flipping portal doesn't have an "All Settings" button nor any listing of Web Jobs that can be created anywhere.  I'm getting so sick of misleading and just plain wrong Azure doco / tutorials.  The crazy part is this is a recent article.

Comment: In Azure Portal, click on `+ New`, from there type in search box `Azure WebJobs`, which eventually will show you the option `Azure WebJobs (preview)`. Or for simplicity, use [this link](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Marketplace/GalleryFeaturedMenuItemBlade/selectedMenuItemId/home/searchQuery/Azure%20WebJobs). I think once found, you can go from there.

Comment: Groan. SO it's on the Marketplace, not a built in feature. Thanks mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article that you mentioned assumes that you have an Azure App Service created. Once that is done and you navigate to the blade for the App Service, the All Settings and Web Job options appear.

Comment: Yeah I finally found the item under Marketplace following Michael's directions.  I'm not really sure I understand why it's an Api Service.  I'm currently running the QueueClient.OnMessage call in an OWIN website but there's no page or api endpoints defined, it merely is a way to bootstrap the instancing of the queueclient.  What I really want is something like a good old System Service running and all the time without having to poll the site to trigger appdomain reload after an app pool refresh.  Withe the Azure Web Job do App Pool Refreshes occur requiring a trigger to reload?

Comment: Web jobs created under and app service are not Api services. They can be configured to be continuously running just like a traditional service.

Comment: Ok so even though it says "API app host" that's still not an Api Service but a permanently running application?

Comment: Honestly, I have never made a webjob through the marketplace, so I can't speak of how that differs from a web job that is running under an app service. I know that a web job under an app service can be set up to run continuously.

Comment: Are you able to point me to working steps on how to create the same kind of App Services you've created?

Comment: Using the marketplace, create a "Web App". From this link, it should be the top search result: https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Marketplace/GalleryFeaturedMenuItemBlade/selectedMenuItemId/home/searchQuery/Web%20APp/resetMenuId/ . Once you create it, follow the link you originally provided in the question.